# Flutter auto_route v6 navigation issue

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-navigation

I am creating a basic app to understand the working of the auto_route library but simple navigation are not working. I am not sure if there is any issue with the setup below is the code. This is the error I am getting

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: 
Looks like you're trying to navigate to a nested route without adding their parent to stack first
try navigating to Home -> Page1
#0      RoutingController._matchOrReportFailure (package:auto_route/src/router/controller/routing_controller.dart:205:9)
#1      StackRouter._push (package:auto_route/src/router/controller/routing_controller.dart:1031:17)
#2      StackRouter.push (package:auto_route/src/router/controller/routing_controller.dart:978:35)
#3      HomeScreen.build.<anonymous closure> (package:auto_route_practice/home.dart:19:32)
#4      _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1096:21)
#5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:253:24)
#6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:627:11)
#7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:306:5)
#8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointe<…>
```

this is the code for the app_router.dart

```
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'package:auto_route_practice/empty_route_widget.dart';
import 'package:auto_route_practice/home.dart';
import 'package:auto_route_practice/page_1.dart';
import 'package:auto_route_practice/page_2.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

part 'app_router.gr.dart';

AppRouter autoRouter = AppRouter();

@AutoRouterConfig(replaceInRouteName: "Route")
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {
  @override
  final List<AutoRoute> routes = [
    AutoRoute(
      page: Home.page,
      path: "/",
      children: [
        // RedirectRoute(path: '', redirectTo: "page1"),
        AutoRoute(page: Page1.page, path: "page1"),
      ],
    ),
  ];
}
```

here is my main.dart file

```
import 'package:auto_route_practice/app_router.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      routerConfig: autoRouter.config(navigatorObservers: () {
        return [AppObserver()];
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my home page from where I am trying to navigate

```
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'package:auto_route_practice/app_router.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

@RoutePage(name: 'home')
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("HomeScreen"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                context.router.navigate(const Page1());
              },
              child: const Text("page 1")),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using children's property inside your `routes.dart` file. Therefore you also have to setup one EmptyRouter so that the scope of your routing can be defined.

Add this code below your `routes.dart` file like this:

```js
@RoutePage(name: 'EmptyRouter')      
class EmptyRouterPage extends AutoRouter {}
```

You can try to add a router config like this:

```js
@AutoRouterConfig(replaceInRouteName: "Route")
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {
  @override
  final List<AutoRoute> routes = [
    AutoRoute(
      page: Home.page,
      path: "/",
      children: [
        page: EmptyRouter.page,
        path: '',
        children: [
        AutoRoute(page: Page1.page, path: "page1"),
        ],
      ],
    ),
  ];
}
```

Now you can try to naviagte to the page like this:

```js
@RoutePage(name: 'home')
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("HomeScreen"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                context.router.navigate(const EmptyRouter());
              },
              child: const Text("page 1")),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am currently doing it outside of any class as global variable since its test app. Later i will be using dependency injection for this. Is there any reason or difference doing it as you mentioned?

Comment: Hi @umuieme, I have refactored the answer, please check it

Comment: there is syntax error in your code. but I put an AutoRoute inside children of home with EmptyRouter but it is not working.